# Is Jeremiah 10:2-5 referring to a Christmas Tree?

Tags: exegesis, christmas, jeremiah

> "Thus saith the LORD, Learn not the way of the
>   heathen, and be not dismayed by the signs in heaven; For the heathen
>   are dismayed at them. For the customs of the people are vain: for one
>   cutteth the tree out of the forest, the work of the hands of a
>   worksman, with the axe. They deck it with silver and gold; they fasten
>   it with nails and hammers, that it move not. They are upright as the
>   palmtree, but speak not: they must needs be borne, because they cannot
>   go. Be not afraid of them; for they cannot do evil, neither also is it
>   in them to do good." [(Jeremiah 10:2-5; KJV)](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Jeremiah%2010%3A2-5&version=KJV)

Can anyone answer this with scripture? (Malachi 3:6 For I am the LORD, I change not; therefore ye sons of Jacob are not consumed.) Why do we celebrate Christmas with a tree? Or at all for that matter?

Answer (score 3):

> Why do we celebrate Xmas with a tree? Or at all for that matter?

We can celebrate Christmas with a tree because the Bible does not prohibit it. Jer. 10 does not refer to the practice of celebrating Christmas and decorating a Christmas tree. Rather, it refers to the heathens (idolaters) cutting a tree out of the forest, making a wooden idol (a god), and then decorating it.

Compare:

- [Jer. 10:5](http://www.blueletterbible.org/Bible.cfm?b=Jer&c=10&v=5&t=KJV#s=t_conc_755005)

> They are upright as the palm tree, but **speak** not: they must needs be borne, because they cannot **go**. Be not afraid of them; for they cannot **do evil**, neither also is it in them to **do good**. (KJV)

Nobody would think a tree speaks, moves, does evil, or does good. But the heathens did believe their idols had such powers.

- [Jer. 10:11](http://www.blueletterbible.org/Bible.cfm?b=Jer&c=10&v=11&t=KJV#s=t_conc_755011)

> Thus shall ye say unto them, The **gods** that have not made the heavens and the earth, even they shall perish from the earth, and from under these heavens. (KJV)

- [Jer. 10:14](http://www.blueletterbible.org/Bible.cfm?b=Jer&c=10&v=11&t=KJV#s=t_conc_755014)

> Every man is brutish in his knowledge: every founder is confounded by the **graven image**: for his **molten image** is falsehood, and there is no breath in them. (KJV)

We celebrate Christmas to commemorate the birth of our Lord Jesus Christ, even if we are not certain of the exact date he was born.